# Calculate the average of sections of a column with condition met to create new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, slice

I have the below data table

```
A = [2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1, 5, 3, 1, 7, 5]
B = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':A, 'B':B})
```

I'd like to calculate the average of column A when consecutive rows see column B equal to 1. All rows where column B equal to 0 are neglected and subsequently create a new dataframe like below:

[image: Desired table]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keywords: `groupby`, `shift`, `mean`

---

Code:

```py
df_result=df.groupby((df['B'].shift(1,fill_value=0)!= df['B']).cumsum()).mean()
df_result=df_result[df_result['B']!=0]
```

```
df_result
     A    B
1  2.0  1.0
3  3.0  1.0
```

---

As you might noticed, you need first to determine the consecutive rows blocks having the same values.
One way to do so is by shifting B one row and then comparing it with itself.

```py
df['B_shifted']=df['B'].shift(1,fill_value=0) # fill_value=0 to return int and replace Nan with 0's
```

```
df['A']                     =[2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1, 5, 3, 1, 7, 5]
df['B']                     =[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
df['B_shifted']             =[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
(df['B_shifted'] != df['B'])=[F, T, F, F, T, F, T, F, F, T, F]
                                [↑      ][↑   ][↑      ][↑   ]
```

Now we can use the groupby pandas method as follows:

```py
df_grouped=df.groupby((df['B_shifted'] != df['B']).cumsum())
```

Now if we looped in the DtaFrameGroupBy object `df_grouped`
we'll see the following tuples:

```
(0,    A  B  B_shifted
0  2  0          0)
(1,    A  B  B_shifted
1  3  1          0
2  1  1          1
3  2  1          1)
(2,    A  B  B_shifted
4  4  0          1
5  1  0          0)
(3,    A  B  B_shifted
6  5  1          0
7  3  1          1
8  1  1          1)
(4,     A  B  B_shifted
9   7  0          1
10  5  0          0)
```

We can simply calculate the mean and filter the zero values now as follow

```py
df_result=df_grouped.mean()
df_result=df_result[df_result['B']!=0][['A','B']]
```

## References:([link](https://www.codeforests.com/2021/03/30/group-consecutive-rows-in-pandas/), [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/pandas-dataframe-group-by-consecutive-same-values-128913875dba?source=rss----7f60cf5620c9---4)).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
m = (df.B != df.B.shift(1)).cumsum() * df.B
df_out = df.groupby(m[m > 0])["A"].mean().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame()
df_out["B"] = 1
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
   A  B
0  2  1
1  3  1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 = df.groupby((df['B'].shift() != df['B']).cumsum()).mean().reset_index(drop=True)
df1 = df1[df1['B'] == 1].astype(int).reset_index(drop=True)
df1
```

**Output**

```
    A   B
0   2   1
1   3   1
```

**Explanation**

We are checking if each row's value of B is not equal to next value using [pd.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html), if so then we are grouping those values and calculating its mean and assigning it to new dataframe `df1`.

Since we have mean of groups of all consecutive 0s and 1s, so we are then filtering only values of `B==1`.

Comment: This approach works however if I changed mean to std it would convert all values in column B to 0 that I no longer can do any filtering. Any other thought?

Comment: I ended up creating a data frame that has the all the statistics of column A and insert column B from the groupby.mean to make this work.